# docker installation in ubuntu and start problem

Tags: docker, installation

I'm unable to start docker service in ubuntu 18.04.

How do I install docker, and how do I start the start docker service?

When running `systemctl start docker` I got this error:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

Comment: how did you install docker?, can you share the commands you have ran.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error related to Ubuntu Linux service error, not by Docker

You Can Use
`sudo service docker start/status/stop` instead of `systemctl`

Comment: i use sudo service docker start but i got "docker: unrecognized services"

Comment: @jananidurairajan That means docker is not installed properly.
Please recheck and install it. You can find steps.. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: can you send the steps in commands it is difficult to me to understand

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use: sudo service docker start

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't require any explicit commands to start its service.

Kindly use steps shared in below like for Setting up docker in Debian i.e Linux machine

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

you can get rid of using sudo for every command by doing this [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)